# How do I use Sql Queries in Crystal Report?

Tags: .net, ado.net, crystal-reports

Ok I want to create a Crystal report and I want to use Sql Queries.I know the sql queries that I want to use but how do I use them in Crystal reports?
The data of crystal reports is taken from a Database and I am using filtering but I need use a value from a text box as 'Where' in my Query. So how do I do it?
I am a beginner at Dot Framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, lets see how you can achieve that for example in VB.NET.

(If you are using a version of Visual Studio.NET greater than 2008, download and install Crystal Reports first since it's not embedded.)

Open Visual Studio.NET. Create a new WindowsForms application by clicking, File -> New Project -> Visual Basic - Windows Forms Application. In the case of Visual Studio.NET 2010, you must change the .NET Framework of your project to .NET Framework 4 (not Client Profile) so you can find the Crystal Reports Viewer in the Reporting tab of the Toolbox. Drag and drop from the Toolbox a TextBox, a Button and a CrystalReportsViewer onto the form. The first 2 are located in the Common Controls tab and the third in the Reporting tab. To create a Report File, click Project -> Add New Item and select Crystal Reports. After that the Crystal Reports Gallery window will appear (or if it don't, double click on the Report File from the Solution Explorer). Select either the wizard or the blank report.

To create a parameter for a query, do it the same way as shown here http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BHNHsIUbcn8 .After creating the parameterized query in the Report File, go back to the form by double clicking it from the Solution Explorer and press F7 to go into the code view. Add the following code inside the Class of your form.

```
Dim Report1 As New CrystalReport1

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Report1.SetDatabaseLogon("Username", "Password")
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Report1.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", TextBox1.Text)
    CrystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1
End Sub
```

Replace the "Username" and the "Password" with the credentials of your Database and the "ParameterName" with the parameter that you added in the Crystal Report inside the {?ParameterName}.

Comment: Ok I have made five commands.It would be nice if you could explain me in C#

Comment: CrystalReport1 Report1 = new CrystalReport1();

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report1.SetDatabaseLogon("Username", "Password");
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Report1.SetParameterValue("ParameterName", textBox1.Text);
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = Report1;
        }